# Ubuntu 18.04 Find Faulty HDD/Controller

Tags: hard-drive, dmesg

Hi Guys been running an Ubuntu server for several years now , mainly to house my disc rips and various PC backups from around the house, last week the system became non responsive, upon getting into safe mode i noticed one of my RAID6 array's was resyncing, looking at DMESG I can see one or several of my disks have issues, this system is based off an older backblaze design using port multipliers, is there an easy way to translate the ATA errors into /dev/sdX I have a drive map drawn up so if i can find which drives are going funky I can change the SATA Cable/Port Multiplier/HBA

Im having issues posting the DMESG log here it posts like word spaghetti no matter what tags I attempt any suggestions, on getting the output on this post, many thanks

Ok hopefully this shows up better, im trying to find the /dev/sd* once i have that i can get the serial numbers of the drives and troubleshoot the hardware further, thanks

```
[  329.382897] ata9: spurious interrupt (slot_stat 0xfffffe active_tag -84148995 sactive 0x0)
[  359.587453] ata9.00: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  359.587458] ata9.01: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  359.587459] ata9.02: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  359.587461] ata9.03: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  359.587463] ata9.04: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  359.587464] ata9.05: failed to read SCR 1 (Emask=0x40)
[  359.587470] ata9.15: exception Emask 0x4 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x280000 action 0x6 frozen
[  359.587511] ata9.15: irq_stat 0x00060002
[  359.587530] ata9.15: SError: { 10B8B BadCRC }
[  359.587552] ata9.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0xaeaaa0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  359.587584] ata9.00: irq_stat 0x00060002, device error via SDB FIS
[  359.587612] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.587638] ata9.00: cmd 60/e8:28:d8:00:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 5 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 8c/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:80:52:8c/00 Emask 0x3 (HSM violation)
[  359.587702] ata9.00: status: { Busy }
[  359.587719] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.587745] ata9.00: cmd 60/e0:38:c0:08:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 7 ncq dma 1032192 in
                        res 60/e0:38:c0:08:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.587809] ata9.00: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.587827] ata9.00: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.587845] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.587871] ata9.00: cmd 60/e8:48:a0:10:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 9 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 60/e8:48:a0:10:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.587934] ata9.00: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.587952] ata9.00: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.587970] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.587996] ata9.00: cmd 60/e8:58:88:18:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 11 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 60/e8:58:88:18:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.588060] ata9.00: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.588078] ata9.00: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.588096] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.588122] ata9.00: cmd 60/e8:68:70:20:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 13 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 60/e8:68:70:20:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.588187] ata9.00: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.588205] ata9.00: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.588223] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.588249] ata9.00: cmd 60/e8:78:58:28:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 15 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 60/e8:78:58:28:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.588313] ata9.00: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.588331] ata9.00: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.588349] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.588374] ata9.00: cmd 60/18:88:40:30:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 tag 17 ncq dma 12288 in
                        res 60/18:88:40:30:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x81 (invalid argument)
[  359.588439] ata9.00: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.588457] ata9.00: error: { IDNF }
[  359.588474] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.588500] ata9.00: cmd 60/e8:90:58:30:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 18 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 60/e8:90:58:30:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.588564] ata9.00: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.588582] ata9.00: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.588600] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.588625] ata9.00: cmd 60/e0:98:40:38:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 19 ncq dma 1032192 in
                        res 60/e0:98:40:38:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.588689] ata9.00: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.588707] ata9.00: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.588725] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.588751] ata9.00: cmd 60/e8:a8:20:40:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 21 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 60/e8:a8:20:40:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.588815] ata9.00: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.588833] ata9.00: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.588851] ata9.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.588877] ata9.00: cmd 60/d8:b8:08:48:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 23 ncq dma 1028096 in
                        res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x5 (timeout)
[  359.590237] ata9.00: status: { DRDY }
[  359.591627] ata9.01: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  359.593021] ata9.02: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x11555f SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  359.594371] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.595688] ata9.02: cmd 60/e8:00:08:f1:0d/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 8c/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:80:08:8c/00 Emask 0x2 (HSM violation)
[  359.598221] ata9.02: status: { Busy }
[  359.599461] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.600105] ata9.02: cmd 60/e8:08:58:30:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 1 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 60/e8:08:58:30:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.601320] ata9.02: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.601920] ata9.02: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.602515] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.603149] ata9.02: cmd 60/e8:10:f0:f8:0d/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 2 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 8c/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:00:20:8c/00 Emask 0x2 (HSM violation)
[  359.604413] ata9.02: status: { Busy }
[  359.605046] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.605641] ata9.02: cmd 60/e0:18:40:38:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 3 ncq dma 1032192 in
                        res 60/e0:18:40:38:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.606839] ata9.02: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.607461] ata9.02: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.608075] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.608669] ata9.02: cmd 60/e8:20:d8:00:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 4 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 8c/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:00:40:8c/00 Emask 0x2 (HSM violation)
[  359.609880] ata9.02: status: { Busy }
[  359.610484] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.611095] ata9.02: cmd 60/e0:30:c0:08:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 6 ncq dma 1032192 in
                        res 8c/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:00:60:8c/00 Emask 0x2 (HSM violation)
[  359.612368] ata9.02: status: { Busy }
[  359.613005] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.613625] ata9.02: cmd 60/e8:40:a0:10:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 8 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 8c/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:00:80:8c/00 Emask 0x2 (HSM violation)
[  359.614874] ata9.02: status: { Busy }
[  359.615548] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.616194] ata9.02: cmd 60/e8:50:88:18:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 10 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 8c/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:00:a0:8c/00 Emask 0x2 (HSM violation)
[  359.617461] ata9.02: status: { Busy }
[  359.618129] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.618786] ata9.02: cmd 60/e8:60:70:20:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 12 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 8c/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:00:c0:8c/00 Emask 0x2 (HSM violation)
[  359.620164] ata9.02: status: { Busy }
[  359.620836] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.621481] ata9.02: cmd 60/e8:70:58:28:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 14 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 8c/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:00:e0:8c/00 Emask 0x2 (HSM violation)
[  359.622817] ata9.02: status: { Busy }
[  359.623530] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.624236] ata9.02: cmd 60/18:80:40:30:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 tag 16 ncq dma 12288 in
                        res 8d/0a:08:08:00:00/00:00:00:00:8d/00 Emask 0x2 (HSM violation)
[  359.625600] ata9.02: status: { Busy }
[  359.626277] ata9.02: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  359.626959] ata9.02: cmd 60/e8:a0:20:40:0e/07:00:74:07:00/40 tag 20 ncq dma 1036288 in
                        res 60/e8:a0:20:40:0e/00:00:74:07:00/40 Emask 0x10 (ATA bus error)
[  359.628351] ata9.02: status: { DRDY DF }
[  359.629047] ata9.02: error: { ICRC UNC }
[  359.629704] ata9.03: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  359.630372] ata9.04: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  359.631038] ata9.05: exception Emask 0x100 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[  359.631744] ata9.15: hard resetting link
[  361.805519] ata9.15: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 0)
[  361.805995] ata9.00: hard resetting link
[  362.118979] ata9.00: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 320)
[  362.119008] ata9.01: hard resetting link
[  362.435156] ata9.01: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  362.435188] ata9.02: hard resetting link
[  362.751010] ata9.02: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  362.751042] ata9.03: hard resetting link
[  363.067005] ata9.03: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[  363.067029] ata9.04: hard resetting link
[  363.382703] ata9.04: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 320)
[  363.382745] ata9.05: hard resetting link
[  363.698837] ata9.05: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 320)
[  363.701958] ata9.00: configured for UDMA/100
[  363.720937] ata9.01: configured for UDMA/100
[  363.724124] ata9.02: configured for UDMA/100
[  363.741791] ata9.03: configured for UDMA/100
[  363.741932] ata9.00: device reported invalid CHS sector 0
[  363.741947] ata9: EH complete
```

Comment: [edit] and add the log formatted as code

Answer (score 0):

You can probably find out the mappings with:

```
find /sys -type d -path '*ata*sd[a-z]'
```

The command should list a few paths that has `ataN` somewhere in the middle and `sdX` at the end. `N` would *normally* be the port number of a corresponding SATA controller.

The paths would also have something like `XXXX:YY:YY.Y` before `ataN`. If you have more than one SATA controllers, you should be able to find out which one a certain `YY:YY.Y` is referring to with the help of `lspci`. (Well, unless they are of the exact same model. That would probably require a few extra steps.)

EDIT: Actually you can probably just

```
ls -l /sys/block/sd* | grep ata
```

Still I have no idea what actually happens when a to z has been used up or what the the `MM` in `ataN.MM` corresponds to.

Comment: Thanks Tom, running that command I see non of the drives in questiion, what is the best way to wrap text here and i will post the dmesg log

Comment: Just put three [backticks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick) (in a separate line) before AND after the whole paste.

Comment: Btw, in the case of simple (e.g. Intel onboard) 6-port SATA controller, ATA errors would have e.g. `ata1.00` for drive under `ata1` (port 1). No idea about backblaze / port multiplier whatsoever.

Comment: @gimpacause what exactly do you get when you run the command given above? Do you not see a single line with `ata9`? What about `find /sys -type d -name ata9`?

Comment: I get the following output

/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata9
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata9/ata_port/ata9

Comment: i get an output like below


/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.1/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:04.0/ata3/host2/target2:2:0/2:2:0:0/block/sdf


but its only showing 26 out of 33 drives in the system

Comment: Hmm I just realize that I have no idea what happens when there are more than 26 "scsi disks" (i.e. using up a to z). So how many "sd*" do you see in `lsblk | grep disk`? How do "sd*" that get past `z` look like?